# How to login from different tables in Yii2 basic application?

Tags: yii2

i have two table : **Admin** and **Employees**.
with different columns name.

how to create database login system for this scenario.

i am using Yii2 basic application.

i don't know how to deal with this problem.

Comment: make one common table users to store user data..or you can check for authentication in both tables.

Comment: how to check for authentication in both tables ??

Comment: make an action and validate data in both tables.

Comment: in user.php : there is code like this..

    public static function tableName()
    {
  return 'admin';
    }
... how to change this for multiple tables ??

Comment: helpful: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/19/how-to-use-a-single-form-to-collect-data-for-two-or-more-models/

Answer (score 2):

One way out of this situation is using abstractions
E.g:

```
abstract class User extends ActiveRecord{
    // abstract method that should overrided child classes
    abstract function tableName();
}

class Admin extends User {
    function tableName() { return 'admin'; }
}

class Employee extends User {
    function tableName() { return 'employee'; }
}
```

But, it's depended on your exact situation. Also you can use setTableName() method for override only table name in the same class.

Comment: Hey @Nuriddin. Nice One Man. Good way to handle 2 table for login.

Comment: Hi @NanaPartykar I owe you one ;)

Answer (score 0):

I agree that it's better to use some common user table. But if you still want to use 2 tables you can do that like this

```
<?php
namespace common\models;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;

/**
 * Login form
 */
class LoginForm extends Model
{
    public $username;
    public $password;
    public $rememberMe = true;

    private $_user = false;

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            // username and password are both required
            [['username', 'password'], 'required'],
            // rememberMe must be a boolean value
            ['rememberMe', 'boolean'],
            // password is validated by validatePassword()
            ['password', 'validatePassword'],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Validates the password.
     * This method serves as the inline validation for password.
     */
    public function validatePassword()
    {
        if (!$this->hasErrors()) {
            $user = $this->getUser();
            if (!$user) {
                $this->addError('password', 'Incorrect username or password.');
                return ;
            }
            if (!$user->validatePassword($this->password)) { // you need to implement this method for both models
                $this->addError('password', 'Incorrect username or password.');
                return ;
            }          
        }
    }

    /**
     * Logs in a user using the provided username and password.
     *
     * @return boolean whether the user is logged in successfully
     */
    public function login()
    {
        if ($this->validate()) {
            return Yii::$app->user->login($this->getUser(), $this->rememberMe ? 3600 * 24 * 30 : 0);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Finds user by [[username]]
     *
     * @return User|null
     */
    public function getUser()
    {
        if (!$this->_user) {
            $this->_user = Employee::findByUsername($this->username);
        } 

        if (!$this->user) {
            $this->_user = Admin::findByUsername($this->username);
        }
        return $this->_user;
    }
}
```

Comment: Argument 1 passed to yii\web\User::login() must implement interface yii\web\IdentityInterface, instance of app\modules\requests\models\TorrentEmployee given, called in /var/www/html/tplportal/common/models/LoginForm.php on line 189 and defined... error occured